# Laravel auto file upload and linking to a model

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application there is a form where user needs to upload files in various places. The way that I am currently trying to implement is by having a auto-upload *(starts uploading as soon as you select or drag n drop a file)* field in those places and by having a dedicated `FilesController` to serve uploading and fetching the file.

So when when someone selects a file, it uploads the file and store the information to files table.

So my question is that when some submits a form with those fields, how will I link those auto-uploaded files to the form?

Should I be return the file id after successful upload and then link it to the form model after form submission? That brought me into another question, how do I handle orphan files (file is uploaded but the user decided not the submit the form)?

*Please Note: I am only seeking advice on how I can achieve it. No code needed.*

Comment: did you already implementing the auto upload ? if not yet try [Dropzone.js](https://www.dropzonejs.com/).
you only need to catch the response from auto upload process and set response value you need to your form.

Comment: @RapSherlock - Yes, I have implemented Dropzone. After successful upload, I am sending the id of the file as response. I can then link the file ID to the model. However, how do I check for orphan files?

Comment: you can also return uploaded file path for more easy to save it to database. for your second question is bit hard, let say someone already upload some file and somehow the connection is closed ? you will need track every unauthored uploaded file, tricky right ? the most realistic way is autosave the form when someone on create page (as draft).

Comment: Yes I agree. The draft approach will work fine. Thanks @RapSherlock 

Comment: u'r welcome and good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

you must write code for change event in input file element

```html
<input type='file' onchange='uploadAsync()' />
<script>
// upload with ajax
</script>
```